# C# age of a webpage?

Tags: c#, web

can you please tell me how I can find the age of a webpage using `C# language`. For example, if I want to find the age of this `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATI_Technologies` website in my C# program, (the day it was first created/uploaded in to the web), how would I do that? Please let me know what would be the activities?

Comment: There is not 1:1 relationship with a server file and response you see. Especially for Wikipedia.

Comment: Crawl the entire web continuously, note for each page when it first appears. Then you'll be able to answer that question. But keep in mind that neither Google nor the Web Archive can do that, which should put your question in a little perspective ...

Comment: Yuck, that's why HTTP addresses *resources*, not *files* ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://archive.org has that information you would need, you could ask them for a webservice to use.

Comment: This might get you pretty close, but it should be said that this isn't 100% reliable. Even if you do trust that archive.org is being truthful with what they've found (healthy skepticism), it's entirely possible that they couldn't/didn't crawl a particular page you're looking for.

Comment: Thats a good point, but you can use a combination with meta-data.

Comment: The combination is absolutely the way to go. I think that archive.org is probably the best option if you had to go single-source, but only if the website in question was documented from its "birth"

Comment: Thanks for all of your infor and help. appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is any reliable way to do that. You would need to count on the publisher having that in the meta-data of the page, and not everyone does.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `Last-Modified` in the HTTP Response Headers.

Comment: Which is not an indicator of when it was *created*.

Comment: I agree, thought that the name is descriptive enough but could provide some information.

Answer (score 0):

If only for Wikipedia articles - you click on "View history" in upper right corner and first entry shows the date:  15:29, 29 July 2004
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ATI_Technologies&dir=prev&action=history

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get that data with a high level of confidence. [WhoIs](http://www.networksolutions.com/whois/index.jsp), [archive.org](http://archive.org)(Thanks HarHaHu, I would have forgotten about that one), and simply asking the owner(s) of the website in quesiton might work to some degree, but the original publishing date for an individual file or url isn't preserved automatically and securely anywhere, even on the host's machine(s). Wikipedia and many other sites do maintain archives and history information on most of their pages, but you have to trust that they aren't fudging data anywhere

A per-page history archive would be a MASSIVE undertaking, and without something like this existing, the data you're looking for simply isn't there with any detail/reliability. There are some ambiguities about what this would even mean: do you track when a particular URL started responding with 200's response codes? Do you track individual files? What if a site relocates, are those new pages, or just old pages? It's a difficult problem to define correctly, and a nearly impossible one to solve completely.